# Lumia 710 problem upgrading to windows phone 7.8

Tags: lumia, update, phone-connector-mac

Location: India

Device : Lumia 710

I connected the device to mac my and launched Windows Phone (for Mac OS X). Checked for updates. It found an update and when I tried to installed it on my Lumia 710, success message also appeared. But to my surprise, My phone is still having Windows Phone 7.5

I used my office mac for that, and used samsung galaxy S III's data cable to connect (As I have lost my Lumia's Data Cable).

Any Idea? Has anyone tried updating their Lumia 710 to Windows Phone 7.8 ?

**EDIT:** while UPDATE was in progress, Red Circle with cross line Over the arrow (from computer symbol to phone symbol) was there? What does this symbol mean?

Comment: That symbol just means "do not disconnect your phone" during the update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have a special phone, it wasn't the update to 7.8. Windows Phone 7.8 for Nokia devices will become available in [December](http://www.winsyde.com/nokias-sergey-rudenko-states-windows-phone-7-8-will-arrive-in-december/). So, you've probably just installed the latest security/bug fix package.

There are rumors that it will launch this week, but the phone manufacturers doesn't need to push those updates immediately, some might even decide to roll out it phases.

**Edit:** Microsoft [confirms](http://www.winbeta.org/news/microsoft-confirms-early-2013-release-windows-phone-78) an early 2013 launch.

Comment: My phone has become "Normal" from "Special" after going through link you provided. Anyways, Thanks for the answer.